# Checkbox, radio buttons on local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I've got a problem about adding my checkboxes and radio buttons to localstorage... Because my radiobuttons depend on my checkbox, when I'm checking one option in checkbox, one of radio button's group shows on screen.
I just wanna to save my radiobuttons and checkboxes in localstorage, load it and alert it in screen when I want... Just don't know how to do it, it's my:
HTML:

I know how to do it with my checkbox (without showing it in an alert, because I don't know how can I do it totally), but I've got problems with radiobuttons, they are showing/hiding when I check my checkbox and I have few groups of that radiobuttons here..

Thanks for the help

```js
function toggleAttributes(checkbox, radios, attribute, attributeValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i += 1) {
    // If checkbox is checked, set the attribute and the attribute value. If not, remove the attribute
    checkbox.checked === true ? radios[i].setAttribute(attribute, attributeValue) : radios[i].removeAttribute(attribute);
  }
}

function toggleRadios(el, id) {
  var radiosSelector = `#${id} input[type='radio']`,
    container = document.getElementById(id),
    radios = document.querySelectorAll(radiosSelector);
  container.classList.toggle("hide");
  toggleAttributes(el, radios, "required", "");
}

var i;
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

function save() {
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        localStorage.setItem(checkboxes[i].value, checkboxes[i].checked); 
    }
}

function load_() {
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = localStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].value) === 'true' ? true:false;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Wybierz dania:
</p>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkGlowne" onclick="toggleRadios(this, 'pierwsze')">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkGlowne">Glowne</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkZupy" onclick="toggleRadios(this, 'zupy')">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkZupy">Zupy</label>
</div>
<p>
  Pierwsze dania:
</p>
<div id = "pierwsze" class = "hide">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="piers">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="piers">Pierś z kaczki</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="stek">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="stek">Stek z antrykotu</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="sandacz">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="sandacz">Sandacz</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="karas">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="karas">Karaś</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id = "zupy" class = "hide">
  <p>
    Zupy:
  </p>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="rosol">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rosol">Rosół z kaczki</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="zurek">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="zurek">Żurek</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="kokosowa">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="kokosowa">Zupa kokosowa</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are saving the state of checkboxes only not the radio buttons

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I know, cuz I don't know how to do it with radio buttons when I have few groups of that.

Comment: added an answer see if it helps , you can see the working fiddle inthe answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that i have added, used `data-target` attribute for dedicating the radio containers with the checkboxes and showing them inside the `load_()` function when the relative checkbox is checked, moreover you should use the `id` of the `checkboxes` and the `radio` boxes to save them in the `localStorage` rather than using value which would be `true` and will be overridden.

Your javascript changes are here

```
 function save() {
        var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            localStorage.setItem(checkboxes[i].id, checkboxes[i].checked);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            localStorage.setItem(radios[i].id, radios[i].checked);
        }
 }

 function load_() {
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = localStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].id) === 'true' ? true : false;

            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                var container = '#' + checkboxes[i].dataset.target;
                document.querySelector(container).classList.toggle("hide");
                var radios = document.querySelectorAll('#' + checkboxes[i].dataset.target + ' input[type="radio"]');
                for (j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
                    radios[j].checked = localStorage.getItem(radios[j].id) === 'true' ? true : false;
                }
            }
        }

 }
```

you html changes are

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkGlowne" data-target="pierwsze" onclick="toggleRadios(this, 'pierwsze')">
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkZupy" data-target="zupy" onclick="toggleRadios(this, 'zupy')">
```

check the `data-target` attribute i has the id of the containers of the radio buttons that are linked to the checkboxes

and here is the working [**`FIDDLE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/h7r0o2fg/11/)

---

**`EDIT`**

For alerting the values that are checked when saving you can change the save function to the following

```
function save() {
        var saved = '';
        var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            localStorage.setItem(checkboxes[i].id, checkboxes[i].checked);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].checked === true) {
                saved += radios[i].id + ' (checked radiobutton)\n';
            }

            localStorage.setItem(radios[i].id, radios[i].checked);
        }
        alert(saved);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, how can I alert my all informations like: zupy: (checked radiobutton), pierwsze (checked radiobutton), dania (checked checkboxes), when I'm clicking save. I know how to do it with text inputs, but not with checkboxes and radio buttons.

Comment: you want the alerts for every radio button separately or all collectively in one alert when all of them are saved @Dr.Weiss

Comment: I wanna one big alert with all these informations, and should I set data-target of radiobuttons by their ID or NAME?

Comment: and should I set data-target of radiobuttons by their ID or NAME?

Comment: see the update , for the alert @Dr.Weiss , you dont need to change anything for the radio buttons.

Comment: Oh, ok it works beauty! Last question: when I have this functions in my .js file.. Where should I put load function if I want to load this localStorage in every page loading?

Comment: you can move the load function along with the rest code into the js file and load the js file on all the pages you want this, straight and simple. @Dr.Weiss

Comment: and do mark the answer as correct  if it worked for you @Dr.Weiss

Comment: Hm, I don't understand it at all... Where should I put: `(function () {
        load_();

    })();` In .js file or in the end of `body`?

Comment: just copy all the `js` along with the load function into the js file, and then load the `.js` file in which ever page you want using `<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>` tag @Dr.Weiss , add it before `</body>` tag

Comment: So I have a problem, because loading doesn't work. Alert and saving are doing well, but when i refresh my page it doesn't show checked checkboxes and radio buttons.

Comment: where are you loading the js file before the `</body>` tag ? @Dr.Weiss

Comment: Yep, it works when I put this code in <script> </script> on the end of body, but when I'm trying to load it by file it doesn't work

Comment: this is odd, it shoulnt be , you must be doing something wrong, can you please add a separate question where you add the script file code and the html page code where you are adding it inside the `script` tag , @Dr.Weiss

Comment: New question or just answer on this question with my code?

Comment: New question , donot paste as an answer @Dr.Weiss

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your HTML and Javascript both.

For security reasons: code not working in snipet try here: https://jsfiddle.net/h7r0o2fg/12/

In HTML, I have added `values` in the `inputs`

And in the script, I have added the radio button condition.

I guess you have logic to call `save()` method, I was calling it manually. Then after refreshing the page, I was calling `load_()` function.

```js
   function toggleAttributes(checkbox, radios, attribute, attributeValue) {
        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i += 1) {
            // If checkbox is checked, set the attribute and the attribute value. If not, remove the attribute
            checkbox.checked === true ? radios[i].setAttribute(attribute, attributeValue) : radios[i].removeAttribute(
                attribute);
        }
    }

    function toggleRadios(el, id) {
        var radiosSelector = `#${id} input[type='radio']`,
            container = document.getElementById(id),
            radios = document.querySelectorAll(radiosSelector);
        container.classList.toggle("hide");
        toggleAttributes(el, radios, "required", "");
    }

    var i;
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    var alertTxt = [];
        function save() {
            alertTxt = [];
            var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
            for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                console.log(checkboxes[i].id, checkboxes[i].checked, checkboxes.length);
                localStorage.setItem(checkboxes[i].id, checkboxes[i].checked);
     if(checkboxes[i].checked == true){
       alertTxt.push(checkboxes[i].value + "(checked checkboxes)");
     }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
                localStorage.setItem(radios[i].id, radios[i].checked);
         if(radios[i].checked == true){
           alertTxt.push(radios[i].value + "(checked radiobutton)");
         }            
    }
           alert(alertTxt);
        }

        function load_() {
            for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = localStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].id) === 'true' ? true : false;

                if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    var container = '#' + checkboxes[i].dataset.target;
                    document.querySelector(container).classList.toggle("hide");
                    var radios = document.querySelectorAll('#' + checkboxes[i].dataset.target + ' input[type="radio"]');
                    for (j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
                        console.log(localStorage.getItem(radios[j].id));
                        radios[j].checked = localStorage.getItem(radios[j].id) === 'true' ? true : false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    // self executing function here
    (function () {
        load_();

    })();
```

```css
 .hide {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<p>
    Wybierz dania:
</p>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkGlowne" data-target="pierwsze" value="pierwsze" onclick="toggleRadios(this, 'pierwsze')">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkGlowne">Glowne</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkZupy" data-target="zupy" value="checkZupy" onclick="toggleRadios(this, 'zupy')">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkZupy">Zupy</label>
</div>
<p>
    Pierwsze dania:
</p>
<div id="pierwsze" class="hide">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="piers" name="pierwsze" value="piers">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="piers">Pierś z kaczki</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="stek" name="pierwsze" value="stek">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="stek">Stek z antrykotu</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="sandacz" name="pierwsze" value="sandacz">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="sandacz">Sandacz</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="karas" name="pierwsze" value="karas">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="karas">Karaś</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="zupy" class="hide">
    <p>
        Zupy:
    </p>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="rosol" name="zupy" value="karas">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rosol">Rosół z kaczki</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="zurek" name="zupy" value="zurek">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="zurek">Żurek</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="kokosowa" name="zupy" value="kokosowa">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="kokosowa">Zupa kokosowa</label>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="save" onclick="save()">
```

Comment: Ok, I see and now I have to call `save` and `load` on button? Next question: how can I put all these values in alert? Like: zupy: (checked radiobutton), pierwsze (checked radiobutton), dania (checked checkboxes)?

Comment: Would you like to show alerts one by one or in only one alert? the `load()` can be called on page load and save can at each event of radio and checkbox

Comment: I only one alert. Can I do it like: save() on clicking submit and load() on clicking load button?

Comment: Yes save() on the submit and load could be at page load. like you can add `load_();` at bottom of the script, so whenever page gets loaded, it will fill all the values. When would you like to show alerts? On load OR on save?

Comment: On saving, when I'm clicking submit

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
function save() {
for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem(checkboxes[i].id, checkboxes[i].checked); 
}


function load_() {
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
        var Ischeck = localStorage.getItem(this.id);
        this.prop('checked', Ischeck)
    });
}
```

Comment: this wont open the radio buttons container it would still be hidden and also the `checkboxes` wont be checked when page is loaded and it will start checking every radio input on the page irrespective of only loading the those that have their respective checkbox checked.